# Set Python WSGIDaemon --maximum-requests value in ElasticBeanstalk Configuration

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, wsgi

I'm looking for instruction on how I would go about setting the `--maximum-requests` value in an AWS ElasticBeanstalk Python environment that is running Django. Note this environment is NOT using a Linux 2 image so gunicorn is not an option nor is using a procfile.

> maximum-requests=nnn Defines a limit on the number of requests a
> daemon process should process before it is shutdown and restarted.
>
> This might be use to periodically force restart the WSGI application
> processes when you have issues related to Python object reference
> count cycles, or incorrect use of in memory caching, which causes
> constant memory growth.
>
> If this option is not defined, or is defined to be 0, then the daemon
> process will be persistent and will continue to service requests until
> Apache itself is restarted or shutdown.
>
> Avoid setting this to a low number of requests on a site which handles
> a lot of traffic. This is because the constant restarting and
> reloading of your WSGI application may cause unecessary load on your
> system and affect performance. Only use this option if you have no
> other choice due to a memory usage issue. Stop using it as soon as any
> memory issue has been resolved.
>
> You can use the graceful-timeout option in conjunction with this
> option to reduce the chances that an active request will be
> interrupted when a restart occurs due to the use of this option.

Comment: How are you running your WSGI daemon? Add some config/code to show what you're running. I've got an EB project running uwsgi via supervisord which passes `max-requests` when the process starts. I'd imagine you'd do something similar.

Comment: I believe EB is running this. I’m not doing anything to start the WSGI daemon. What config files would help?

Comment: Well typically if you're running django in EB you'd use docker to build your application. Now you said you're not using the Linux 2 platform, so it'd be helpful to know how you're building your application & running it to figure out how to customise your WSGI daemon.

Comment: EB is building the application and running it. This is a Django app so locally I just run python manage.py runserver. Does that give you some more insight? I literally just set the path to the WSGI.py file and then did an eb deploy.

Comment: I think that you are probably suggesting that I just run Django using this method. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/ https://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Comment: The above all makes sense to me, but I don't know how I would tell EB to run `uwsgi --http :8000 --module mysite.wsgi`

Comment: Yeah that's a typical way to do it. I still don't understand how your EB environment is running though. Typically you might use CodeBuild and CodePipeline to feed your application into the EB environment, but you said EB is doing everything.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish this I had to create a config in my .ebextensions folder that contained the following.

You will want to copy the wsgi.conf file from your server to make sure that you have the correct settings for EB first.

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/local/override_wsgi_conf.py":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        #!/usr/bin/env python
        import os
        import sys
        sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(
            os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))))
        import config
    
        MY_APACHE_TEMPLATE = r'''
        # Customized wsgi.conf.  If you're seeing this, good!
 
        LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
        WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/baselinenv
        WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
        WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

        <VirtualHost *:80>

        Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/static/
        <Directory /opt/python/current/app/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>


        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/key_collector_backend/wsgi.py


        <Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi processes=3 threads=20 maximum-requests=10000 display-name=%{GROUP} \
        python-home=/opt/python/run/venv/ \
        python-path=/opt/python/current/app user=wsgi group=wsgi \
        home=/opt/python/current/app
        WSGIProcessGroup wsgi
        </VirtualHost>

        LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined

        WSGIPassAuthorization On
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

        '''


        def main():
            try:
                WSGI_STAGING_CONFIG = config.get_container_config('wsgi_staging_config')
                print 'Overriding WSGI configuration in %s' % WSGI_STAGING_CONFIG
                open(WSGI_STAGING_CONFIG, 'w').write(MY_APACHE_TEMPLATE)
            except Exception, e:
                config.emit_error_event(config.USER_ERROR_MESSAGES['badappconfig'])
                config.diagnostic("Error generating config during configdeploy/pre: %s"
                                    % str(e))
                sys.exit(1)
    
    
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            config.configure_stdout_logger()
            main()
 
commands:
 
  5_app_deploy_dir:
    command: "mkdir -p /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre"
  5_config_deploy_dir:
    command: "mkdir -p /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/pre"
 
  10_app_deploy_file:
    command: "cp -p /opt/elasticbeanstalk/local/override_wsgi_conf.py /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/90_override_wsgi_conf.py"
 
  20_config_deploy_file:
    command: "cp -p /opt/elasticbeanstalk/local/override_wsgi_conf.py /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/pre/90_override_wsgi_conf.py"
```

See this thread for the full details.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=163369

Comment: Ha, I see it needed to be overwritten in one of the deploy stages.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the Apache server configuration where the WSGIDaemonProcess directive is used.

SSH to the EC2 instance running your elastic beanstalk application and change to the configuration directory `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`.

Look there for file containing `WSGIDaemonProcess`.

```
grep -rnwl . -e 'WSGIDaemonProcess'
```

Replace the contents of the matched file in your elasticbeanstalk application configuration.

The location of the generated configuration (during staging phase of application deployment) can be conveniently obtained with the shell command:

```sh
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k wsgi_staging_config
```

**.ebextensions/wsgi.config**

```yaml
files:
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/05_wsgi.sh:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      # Set max-requests option in generated wsgi.conf
      sed -i -e '/WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi/ a\
      \ \ maximum-requests=1000 \\
      ' $(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k wsgi_staging_config)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try today!

Comment: From what I can tell this doesn't overwrite /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf.  I created a wsgi.config file in my .ebextensions folder and have the matched file pat set to "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf"

Comment: Just found this article... oh boy... https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=163369